# How to make Document DB LINQ provider to generate ARRAY_CONTAINS query with third parameter

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

It seems like Cosmos DB LINQ provider translate:

```
forms.Where(x => x.Clients.Contains(new Client { Id = 100 })
```

to:

```
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["clients"],{"id":100, "number": null})
```

The model:

```
public class Client
{
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("numner")]
        public int? Number { get; set; }    
}
```

But what I really need is to use `partialMatch` (the third optional parameter for the `ARRAY_CONTAINS`, `false` by default).

So is it way to make LINQ provider to generate the following query?

```
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c["clients"],{"id":100}, true)
```

I tried to use `.Any()` but had an exception(it seems like `Any` is not supported in this context). 
Maybe it's possible to use `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` somehow?